# Which stack exchange should I ask questions about the difference between income brackets for specific jobs?

Tags: support, stackexchange

Which stack exchange should I ask questions about the difference between income brackets for specific jobs?

Specifically, Doctor pay vs CEO pay.

I don't think it should be Personal finance since it's I'm not asking about personal finances, but I don't know if it should be economics or quantitative finance. And honestly, neither of them seem built for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask that question here. That is not quantitative finance question for sure, and it would fall under economics.

However, you should make it more specific. Difference between CEO and doctor pay in which country and what year? Also, by doctor you mean medical doctors or PhD?

Lastly, if you want your question to be well received by the community you should show us some prior research/trying to find answer on your own (questions that can be answered with quick google search are usually received poorly and attract negative reactions/downvotes).

As you find in our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (I recommend looking at the other advice there as well) the first advice for asking good questions is:

> **Search, and research:** Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: I plan on asking about the way in which even the most monetarily effective PhD Researchers make at most a couple million dollars over the course of their careers, whereas CEOs can make over 1000x more over the course of theirs, usually due to asset appreciation. I feel the question will not go over well with the community as my previous questions regarding inequality haven't, I also plan on posting more sources this time, but I don't think that's why my other questions were overlooked.The way I see it even poor questions can lead to interesting insights, if people will give them a chance.

Comment: @Ethan well my recommendation is 1. make sure its a question not a statement. 2. Do at least little bit of background research to make sure it makes sense - I have Msc. in policy economics large part of which covered issues surrounding inequality and redistribution and saying that asset appreciation is an income makes no sense whatsoever. In fact the first thing you will learn is that wealth and income inequality are related but separate issues. For example, if you go on astronomy.se with question is sun made of pile of burning tires or is earth flat you should not expect positive reactions

Comment: Right, I understand now that asset appreciation isn't a form of income, but the fact that CEOs have so much money in their own appreciating assets means that market forces drive their incomes up because in order to pay them a competitive salary that would make them want to work there it needs to compete with the appreciation of their stock assets. So their appreciating assets are driving inequality by detaching their pay from the amount and quality of their work. I'll bring all this up in my question so I just hope it won't get closed this time. (I have no econ degree)